# SQL Query for time intervals. Syntax errors.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

This is the case where a seemingly simple exercise turned to be nothing but.  I couldn't even get my syntax straight.

`Readings` table contains coordinates and time readings for multiple users.  All I want at this time to organize it as consecutive time intervals for each user.

**Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE [Readings] (
user_id varchar(10),
reading_time int, 
x decimal(10,2),
y decimal(10,2) );


INSERT INTO Readings VALUES  
('u1', 60, 345, 400),
('u1', 100, 560,300), 
('u2', 35, 1024, 250), 
('u1', 90, 450, 450), 
('u3', 150, 600, 100), 
('u3', 100, 500, 125);
```

**My erroneous code**:

```
SELECT r.user_id, r.reading_time start_time, rm.reading_time end_time, 
       (CONVERT(varchar, r.x)+' ; '+CONVERT(varchar, r.y)) start_point, 
       (CONVERT(varchar, rm.x)+' ; '+CONVERT(varchar, rm.y)) end_point 
FROM Readings r 
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 r2.user_id, r2.reading_time, r2.x, r2.y
      FROM Readings r2
      WHERE r2.user_id=r.user_id and 
            r2.reading_time < r.reading_time
      ORDER BY r2.reading time desc) rm 
ON r.user_id=rm.user_id
ORDER BY 1,2 desc;
```

Can you please point out my syntax error(s)?

Comment: SQL is the language. Which DBMS are you using? (I suspect SQL-Server from the `TOP` but I could be wrong.) You should also add the version you are using.

Comment: @ypercube looks like sql server based on the square brackets and the `TOP` syntax

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I was playing with SQL Fiddle's **MS SQL Server 2008**.

Comment: Sadistic idea: create a DMBS called SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well part of your problem is you are referencing a table alias inside of a subquery, you can only do that if you are using an [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT r.user_id, 
  r.reading_time start_time, 
  rm.reading_time end_time, 
  (CONVERT(varchar(10), r.x)+' ; '+CONVERT(varchar(10), r.y)) start_point, 
  (CONVERT(varchar(10), rm.x)+' ; '+CONVERT(varchar(10), rm.y)) end_point 
FROM Readings r 
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 r2.user_id, r2.reading_time, r2.x, r2.y
  FROM Readings r2
  WHERE r2.user_id=r.user_id and 
      r2.reading_time < r.reading_time
  ORDER BY r2.reading_time desc
) rm 
ORDER BY 1,2 desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fae71/10)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `JOIN` like that, you need to use either `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` (assuming SQL Server). Also, please add length to varchars. Now, try this:

```
SELECT r.user_id, r.reading_time start_time, rm.reading_time end_time, 
       (CONVERT(varchar(10), r.x)+' ; '+CONVERT(varchar(10), r.y)) start_point, 
       (CONVERT(varchar(10), rm.x)+' ; '+CONVERT(varchar(10), rm.y)) end_point 
FROM Readings r 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 r2.user_id, r2.reading_time, r2.x, r2.y
             FROM Readings r2
             WHERE r2.user_id=r.user_id and 
                   r2.reading_time < r.reading_time
             ORDER BY r2.reading_time desc) rm 
ORDER BY 1,2 desc;
```

[Here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fae71/8) for you to try.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not seem that I need to have **OUTER** since I need only real intervals.