# Oracle syntax error on JOIN to sub-query

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, subquery

The following code is already a reduced sample that still produces syntax error:

`ORA-00904: "R"."READING_TIME": invalid identifier`

```
SELECT r.user_id, rm.reading_time start_time, r.reading_time end_time
FROM Readings r 
INNER JOIN  (
      SELECT r2.user_id, r2.reading_time, r2.x, r2.y
      FROM Readings r2
      WHERE r2.user_id=r.user_id and 
            r2.reading_time < r.reading_time
      ) rm   
ON r.user_id=rm.user_id;
```

Why is the inner query having problem with the alias of the outer query?

Link to my Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d4b5/21

`UPDATE:`
I solved the problem by doing a self-join and moving the correlated query to **ON** clause.

Updated fiddle with the entire script: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39032/10

Comment: Because you cannot join subquery. This is syntax error corrected by Hamlet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query for time intervals. Syntax errors.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100254/sql-query-for-time-intervals-syntax-errors)

Comment: @ ypercube - You're right.  I'm rewriting that query from SQL Server 2008 to Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "rm" inline view has no access to the outer queries columns, so `r.user_id` and `r.reading_time` cannot be referenced in the inner query. You'd have to filter outside:

```
SELECT r.user_id, rm.reading_time start_time, r.reading_time end_time
FROM Readings r 
INNER JOIN  (
      SELECT r2.user_id, r2.reading_time, r2.x, r2.y
      FROM Readings r2
      ) rm   
ON rm.user_id=r.user_id 
AND rm.reading_time < r.reading_time;
```

Comment: So I cannot use correlated sub-query here?

Comment: a correlated subquery is where you have a sub query in the where clause that references a table in the parents from clause - but this situtation doesn't apply here. what I have re-written your query to is the right way i.e. you have the joins outside of the inline view (granted in this trivial case, we could simplify to the same as what hamlet posted, but I assume your real SQL is more complex)

Comment: Can I have a correlated sub-query as a part of **ON** expression?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes. i.e. you could have `select .. from taba a join tabb b on a.id = b.id and a.id in (select c.val from tabc c where c.id=a.id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer from one part of JOIN to another part.

Does you looking for this?

```
SELECT r.user_id, r2.reading_time start_time, r.reading_time end_time
FROM Readings r 
INNER JOIN Readings r2 
ON r.user_id=r2.user_id
   AND r2.reading_time < r.reading_time;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d4b5/24)**

Comment: My code currently does not make any sense. It's just a reduced sample in an attempt to localize the source of the syntax error.